# how to make action on submenu

Tags: android, submenu

```
ArrayList<String> emplist = new ArrayList<String>();

//Inside the array I add list of employee that I query from DB
SubMenu empMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Employee's Map").setIcon(R.drawable.group);

for (int i = 0; i < emplist.size(); i++) {
    empMenu.add(EMPLOYEE, i, i, emplist.get(i));
}
```

I prefer option for user that can select name of employee then I will perform result.
So, my question is how can I get the itemId which relate to user's selected to use in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override [`onOptionsItemSelected`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29) methods in your Activity to get which menu item is selected by calling `getItemId` on the `menuItem` argument. Following is a sample code.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    // process with the item id of user selected menu.
    // ...

    return true
}
```

Comment: I understand this job but I have no idea how to getItemId() which user chose

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. The `item` argument is the menu user selected. `item.getItemId()` will return the menu item id which is also the index of your emplist.

Comment: Thank you I think I got an answer